# text string must be rendered with in <text> component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

when I render an item in text, it show this error and also show after removing text tag from it, it show this error again

```
<View>
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.ads}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.title}
      />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.ads}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(item.title)}
      />
```

then in your component write _renderItem function

```
_renderItem = (item) => {
   return <View>
           <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
}
```

Comment: Remove ```{item.title}``` and just add "hello world" like this. ```<Text>hello world</Text>```

Comment: when i use parentheses with _renderItem() it show undefined not an bject item.title

Comment: you have to apply check on data. because when componentWillMount() function call  then data is empty and when componentDidMount() call then data loads to state . So you have to check for empty data and render list when data is not null.

Comment: constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ads: []
    };
    this.refs = firebase.firestore().collection("ads");
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.refs.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const list = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        list.push({
          title: doc.data().title
        });
      });
      this.setState({ ads: list });
    });
  }

this is the code for data